# al eliminar un objeto de de un arraylist minorar el valor de una variable del arraylist en uno de los objetos posteriores al eliminado

Tags: java

Me explico. Tengo un arraylist con ID de citas 1,2,3,4,5, un objeto aciente y una hora.
Quiero que cuando borre una cita por ejemplo la 3 el ID de la 4 pase a ser 3 y el de la 5 pase a ser 4. Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaDoctoresG.size(); i++) {
    if (listaDoctoresG.get(i).getNombreDoctor().compareToIgnoreCase(cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem().toString()) == 0) {
        listaDoctoresG.get(i).getListaCitas().remove(indice);
        for (int x = 0; x < listaDoctoresG.get(i).getListaCitas().size();x++) {
            Doctor nD = (Doctor) listaDoctoresG.get(i);
            for(int z = indice; z<=nD.getListaCitas().size(); z++ ){
             int nCita = nD.getListaCitas().get(i).getNumerocita();
             nCita -=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Se que le falta algo pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay formas mejores de hacerlo, pero basándome en tu pregunta, aquí tienes una respuesta.

La variable numeroCitas deberia tener la C mayúscula. Y te recomiendo en los objetos no poner un sufijo como  Citas o Doctor. Si ya estás accediendo al objeto Doctor, ya sabes que Doctor.nombre es el nombre del doctor

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaDoctoresG.size(); i++) {

    // El doctor lo tienes desde este punto
    Doctor doctor = listaDoctoresG.get(i);

    if (doctor.getNombreDoctor().equalsIgnoreCase(cmbDoctorSelected)) {

        // Este indice debe ser del tipo primitivo int, no puede ser Integer
        doctor.getListaCitas().remove(indice);

        // Recorre la lista de citas desde la que se ha borrado
        for(int j=indice; j<doctor.getListaCitas().size(); j++) {

            // Actualiza los numeros
            doctor.getListaCitas().get(j).setNumeroCita(
                doctor.getListaCitas().get(j).getNumeroCita()-1);
        }
    }
}
```